# Do lots of files cause OSes to slow to a hault?

Tags: linux, windows, macos

I have a Mac OSX machine that is almost at a stand still. The only thing I can notice is that there are a TON of files. mostly small ones and if I stick the USB drive to another machine is takes FOREVER to load up the files.

So this made me think that maybe its the amount of files that is causing the issues?

Is this just an APPLE or issue or does this also effect WINDOWS AND LINUX? I've never had this problem on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs such as Finder or Explorer may have difficulty reading large numbers of files, especially from slow USB storage. I've seen the problem myself on Finder in the past. I believe it may be related to the structure that the filesystem uses to represent the folder structure and handles large numbers of files inefficiently, but I may be mistaken.